# Admin template in the plugin in NopCommerce 2.1

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc-3, nopcommerce

I'm writing a plugin in NopCommerce 2.1. I'm wondering if there is a way that I can force a view page within the plugin to use the _AdminLayout.cshtml instead of the _Root.cshtml? Is it possible?

Thank you in advanced

Answer (score 0):

In short, the answer is yes ... but i assume you want to know how as well :)

```
@model MyModel
@{
    Layout = "~/admin/Views/Shared/_AdminLayout.cshtml";
}
<div>My HTML</div>
```

I'm quite new to nopCommerce and don't know how the authentication and authorisation works yet, so i don't know the implications of using the admin layout.  I would think it is fine if your plugin is just for the admin site.